# Ошибка при запуске скрипта JS/WDIO

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Execution of 1 spec files started at 2021-08-22T12:11:36.411Z

Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.        
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:111
            return '- ' + specs.join(', ').replace(new RegExp(`${process.cwd()}`, 'g'), '');
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa/: Unmatched ')'
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at WDIOCLInterface.getFilenames (C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:111:52)
    at WDIOCLInterface.onJobComplete (C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:93:70)
    at WDIOCLInterface.onSpecRunning (C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:75:14)
    at WDIOCLInterface.addJob (C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:121:18)
    at WDIOCLInterface.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at WDIOCLInterface.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at WDIOCLInterface.onMessage (C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\interface.js:177:25)
    at WorkerInstance.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at WorkerInstance.emit (domain.js:470:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio@1.0.0 test:TestTimeLimitDueDate.spec.js: `cross-env TESTS_ENV=stage npm run config && ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config/wdio.chrome.conf.js --spec ./test/specs/books/TestTimeLimitDueDate.spec.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio@1.0.0 test:TestTimeLimitDueDate.spec.js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hehe)\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-22T12_11_38_740Z-debug.log
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run test:TestTimeLimitDueDate.spec.js" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Вот что происходит после запуска

Comment: о чём вам говорит `expression: /C:\Users\hehe)\Desktop\try2\diderot-qa/: Unmatched ')'`?

Comment: @nörbörnën в пути отсутствует скобочка?

Comment: скобочка из "пути" попадает в `new RegExp(process.cwd(), 'g')` и ломает его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас путь к текущей директории включает некоторые символы, которые имеют особое значения в регулярках. Поэтому у вас два выхода: или сначала экранировать все особые символы (вставить перед ними `\` через `.replace()`) — или не использовать регулярные выражения, благо уже есть способ заменить все подстроки и без регулярок:

```js
return '- ' + specs.join(', ').replaceAll(process.cwd(), '');
```

Comment: думаю, проблема возникает не из-за кода, написанного автором вопроса, а в коде инсталлятора wdio и единственным решение её станет переименование текущего пользователя или его домашнего каталога

Comment: @nörbörnën Какое-то слишком радикальное решение) Может, просто переместить проект в папку с путём попроще. Но ведь слеши тоже по идее меняют смысл регулярки? Возможно, это повод написать разработчикам.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty попробовал ваш способ, не помогло, теперь другая ошибка - replaceAll(...) - not a function, попробую изменить название дом каталога

Comment: @Vladeezy Возможно, у вас немного устаревшая версия Node.js, `replaceAll()` поддерживается начиная с 15-й.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty ну нод я сегодня устанавливал, последнюю версию по идее же, просто винду решил поменять и почему то вдруг появилась эта проблема. Ну в целом, только что переименовал папку домашнюю, она называлась у меня "hehe)" и стала "hehe", попробовал запустить - фейл. В итоге только что переустановил нод и все заработало, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @nörbörnën вам тоже спасибо!